How to use Windows IIS to forward requests from website.com/page to localhost without using port forwarding?
I have two different game servers running on my Windows 11 computer for friends and family, each with its own built-in web server. They are dependant of the game server process and run standalone alongside the game servers. They run on different ports. They are not websites or applications in the IIS.
I want to use IIS to forward them through user-friendly URLs, like website.com/page_one and website.com/page_two, instead of specifying a port.
I chose IIS because I already have an SSL certificate set up in the MMC, and I want to use port 443 for these servers. Currently, I can access the web servers locally via http://localhost:port, and from other devices via website.com:port if I configure port forwarding in my router. However, I want to avoid using port forwarding and instead handle everything through IIS and ARR (Application Request Routing).
I installed IIS, I have only one site (Default Web Site), enabled ARR proxy, and used URL Rewrite to create reverse proxy rules for these URLs:
Pattern: /page_one(.*)
Rewrite URL: http://localhost:11111/%7BR:1%7D
Pattern: /page_two(.*)
Rewrite URL: http://localhost:22222/%7BR:1%7D
Expected: Requests to website.com/page_one or /page_two would be forwarded to the respective internal web servers running on ports 11111 and 22222.
None of these rules worked as expected.
404 errors, or
Infinite redirect loops, where /page_one kept getting appended multiple times in the URL (e.g., /page_one/page_one/...).
I also tried many different pattern and rewrite combinations (that I can't share in this message because the automation flags my question as spam).
Pattern: (.*)
Rewrite URL: http://localhost:port/{R:1}
This worked, but forwarded all requests to a specific server, making it impossible to handle both servers based on a specific URL prefix.
Following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/troubleshoot-arr-using-frt-rules and enabling FRT breaks everything and I get Internal server error 500 if I go to website.com or website.com/pages. FRT logs are not generated in the specified folder.
In the F12 window it says
Request URL:https://website.com/page_one
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
in the console I can find this
content.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target')
The page itself shows
Server Error
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
If I don't try to add the tracing rules I get no errors, but I don't get any error logs either.
Only logs I can find are in \inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1 like u_ex241024.log
and they contain information like this:
date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2024-10-24 01:38:57 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx GET /page_one - 443 - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/130.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 - 404 0 2 100
For testing, I always use normal browser window, private browser window and F12 developer mode with "Disable cache" option enabled.
I start with normal view, then I open the F12 developer mode and last I open up a new private window.
While I was looking for possible causes for the problems, I came across somewhere that the Physical Path would be like \inetpub\wwwroot\page_one but I can't find where I saw that. The only things I have in my \inetpub\wwwroot folder are three files "iisstart.htm", "iisstart.png" and "web.config". If that path is true no wonder I get the 404 with pattern /page_one(.*) because it doesn't exist.
I tried adding the physical locations of the game server web servers as virtual directories to IIS Default Web Site, but I get error 500.19 with /page_one and with /page_two I get
GET https://website.com/files/static/css/main.75aa5e01.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) page_two/:1
GET https://website.com/files/static/js/main.6d2039c8.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) manifest.json:1
GET https://website.com/manifest.json 404 (Not Found) manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
In the \inetpub\wwwroot\web.config the working rules look like this:
<rule name="ReverseProxy_11111" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:11111/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
</rule>

And the not working rules look like this:
<rule name="ReverseProxy_11111" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="/page_one(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:11111/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
    </rule>

Summary;
I need a solution to configure IIS to:
Forward requests from website.com/page_one to localhost:11111 and website.com/page_two to localhost:22222.
Avoid infinite redirect loops and properly maintain the /page_one and /page_two paths in the URL.
Use port 443 with SSL and avoid router-level port forwarding.
Any guidance or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

There may be something wrong with the URL rewrite you configured. You can try using failed request tracing to view detailed information.

I added more info about the FRT in my question and I also added what the rules look like.

You can try to enable the ARR proxy feature of IIS and use the URL Rewrite module to set up reverse proxy rules for /page_one and /page_two to rewrite the requests to local ports 11111 and 22222 respectively. Make sure to use {R:1} to preserve the URL path to avoid redirection loops. At the same time, bind an SSL certificate, use port 443 for encrypted access.

Thank you for the suggestion. I already have ARR proxy enabled and I have reverse proxy rules made with Rewrite module. Unfortunale they don't work for me. There's more information about it in my question.

It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.
